# Sitecore MVC editable link in page editor

Tags: asp.net-mvc, sitecore, sitecore8

I'm trying to output a link and link text from a custom model so it is editable in the page editor. It works fine normally but not in the page editor.
In my model class i have 2 strings like this:

```
public string Link { get; set; }
public string LinkText { get; set; }
```

I try to make the text editable in a repository like this:

```
model.LinkText = FieldRenderer.Render(item, "Link Text");
model.Link = LinkManager.getItemUrl(item);
```

in my .cshtml file i am outputting the fields like this:

```
<a href="@Model.Link>@Model.LinkText<a/>
```

Am i going about this the wrong way or can i get this code to work with some tweaks ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To get the editors to work in the page editor, you would need to change the type of your property.

Change

```
public string Link { get; set; }
```

to

```
public IHtmlString Link { get; set; }
```

That will allow MVC to render the html components of the page editor. That should take care of your link text in the page editor.

To make the link editable would depend on what the field type is.

Comment: I don't need to make the link editable so so what you suggested works perfectly. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

This depends on the field type you have on your template.

If you are using a general link field You would need to use a single property in your model for the link (of type HtmlString). The way you are initialising your 'LinkText' property is fine. In your razor code you would just use @Model.PropertyName.

If you are using two separate fields for the target page and the link text, you would instead need to use edit frames (not sure of the mvc equivalent for this) or a custom page editor button to open a popup where the field can be edited content editor style.

Answer (score 0):

Try somthing like This, and the Link field should be General Link. :

```
@using (BeginRenderLink(x => x.Link, isEditable: true))
{
    @Editable(x => x.Title);
}
```

Comment: You're assuming OP is using `Glass.Mapper` which he has not mentioned.

Comment: Yes I just noticed that :)

Comment: And even when using Glassmapper, you could just use a `RenderLink(x => x.Link, isEditable: true)` because a GeneralLink fields (maps to Glass.Mapper.Sc.Fields.Link) has its own title description field. Let's not introduce an additional string for something that's already there.